# how to parse a backbone collection in a template view

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, mustache

I am using backbone and i would like to parse my first collection in my view.

My first question, is `undescore` really the best way to do it? I have heard about `mustache.js`

The next thing is, i don't know how to do is:

```
var A = new Model();
var B = new Model();
var Mole = new Collection([A, B]);
var View = View({model: A, collection: Mole });
View.render();
```

Here is my render method:

```
render: function(){
  this.template = _.template($('template').html());
  $(this.el).html(this.template(this.collection.models)); //I don't know what to send here
}
```

Here is my template

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
  <% _.each(collection, function(model){ %> //I don't know what to get here
    <% model.name %>
  <% }); %>
</script>
```

Comment: Whatever you give to the template is what you can access.  Since you are passing `this.collection.models` there is no property `collection` available.  If you pass `this` to the template your template code might work.

Comment: Ok, i just tried to send `this` but i can't access the collections this way in my template, it doesn't enter to the `_.each`.
I do have 2 models in my collaction.

Comment: If you pass `this` with the code you posted, i think you need to do <%= model.get('name') %> in the template.

Comment: Passing `this` won't get you anywhere at all, you need to give your data a name `this.template({ some_name: ... })` or the template will try to use the whole object as the namespace and that's not what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, you are using mustache?  I got the impression you were using underscore templates. If you are using Mustache disregard anything I said :)

Comment: @Paul: I think they're using Underscore templates but thinking about maybe using Mustache if it is easier. At least that's my take on things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, `_.template` wants the text from the template, not a jQuery object. That means that this:

```
this.template = _.template($('template'));
```

should be this:

```
this.template = _.template($('template').html());
```

Then the compiled template function will want to see key/value pairs for the data; from the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template) (this applies to Mustache, Handlebars, and Underscore BTW):

> When you evaluate a template function, pass in a **data** object that has properties corresponding to the template's free variables.

So you want to say this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template({
    collection: this.collection.toJSON()
}));
```

and then you can say this in your template:

```
<% _.each(collection, function(model) { %>
  <%= model.name %>
<% }); %>
```

A couple points to consider:

1. Backbone views already have a jQuery wrapped `this.el` in [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) so there's no need to `$(this.el)`.
2. Serialized data is generally passed to templates using [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON), this applies doubly so to Mustache and Handlebars since they won't understand anything else.
3. You need to say `<%= ... %>` to get some output in your template; `<% ... %>` simply evaluates a bit of JavaScript code, it won't leave anything behind, you have to use interpolation delimiters (`<%=` and `%>` by default) for that.

Comment: It is good, but you don't necessarily have to pass JSON to the underscore template method. You can pass any javascript object and call functions or access properties on it. I.e. you can pass a backbone model and use <%= get('SomeAttribute') %>

Comment: @Paul: You can pass a whole collection but serializing it with `toJSON` is more common, hence the *generally* in "Serialized data is generally passed to templates using [...]"; you'll have to give it a name in any case. If you're dealing with Mustache then you can't pass the whole collection object at all as Mustache won't know what to do with it. Passing the `toJSON` version also helps avoid odd side effects if your template accidentally alters its data.

Comment: Just a note, but I think the each line would want to read
<%_.each(collection.models, function(model) {%>

Comment: @JonRed: Not quite. I have `collection: this.collection.toJSON()` when calling the template function so `collection` will be an array inside the template. If `collection` was the whole collection (rather than the JSON version), then you'd use `_.each(collection.models, ...)` or `collection.each(...)`.